# gridheight doesn't affect my buttons

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I am new in java applications and I am trying to create a window with 3 buttons in a row at the bottom of the window with extended size. However gridheight doesn't have any affect on my buttons. gridwidth works fine.

Can you give me a feedback on what I am doing wrong? I guess I haven't understand something correctly.

Bellow is my code and the output window.

Thanx in advance!

```
private JButton button1;
private JButton button2;
private JButton button3;

public SessionTasksPage() 
{
     JPanel p1=new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
     JPanel p2=new JPanel();

     button1 = new JButton("b1");    
     button2 = new JButton("b2"); 
     button3 = new JButton("b3");

     GridBagConstraints gbc =new GridBagConstraints();

     //gbc.insets = new Insets(1,1,1,1);

     gbc.gridheight = 5;
     gbc.gridwidth = 5;
     gbc.weightx=15;
     gbc.weighty=15;
     gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

     p1.add(button2,gbc);
     p1.add(button3,gbc);
     p1.add(button1,gbc);

     add(p1,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
     add(p2,BorderLayout.NORTH);

     EventHandler1 event1 = new EventHandler1();
     button1.addActionListener(event1);

     //window terminate setting 
     setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     //window size
     setSize(600,400);
     //pack();
     //make window visible
     setVisible(true);
     //window title
     setTitle("HCI-Projet");
     //voice command
     //new AePlayerWave("bin/sounds/login.wav").start();
}

public class EventHandler1 implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event1) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: How is gridwidth doing anything different? You have it set to the same number as gridHeight, 5, and neither the width nor the height of those buttons looks like 5 pixels.

Comment: it affects. the default width of the buttons (if I put gbc.gridwidth = 5; as a comment) is much smaller

Comment: @user1866935 If you do find that a particular solution **works** for you, marking it as accepted can really help people who come behind you, and read your question, and have the same issues.  If a particular solution **doesn't work** for you, leave some comments or create a discussion so that we can help you solve your problem.

I promise I'm not saying this just because I have an answer below; if the other answer helped you, accept that one!

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh - gridHeight doesn't mean anything in pixels.  Rather, it refers to the height as a number of cells in a grid within the GridBagLayout.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies the layout of your main panel.  `BorderLayout`, which you use on that panel, has one large central area (`BorderLayout.CENTER`), and many smaller areas (such as `NORTH` and `SOUTH`).  The layout will force anything put anywhere other than `CENTER` to take up the smallest amount of room possible, and max out the remaining room with what is in the `CENTER` area (with nothing, in this case).   Since you're adding `p1` as SOUTH, it keeps the vertical component of `p1` as small as it can.  If you add `p1` as `CENTER`, it should fix your problem.

As a side note, if all the rows/columns in your grid will have the same height/width, you may find using `GridLayout` much easier than `GridBagLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the JPanel p1.  The space of the panel is created by the standard layout, and if you just use `add(p1,BorderLayout.SOUTH);`, it won't change.

To make it visible you could use a Border:
`p1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));`

Use a different layout or a GUI builder.

Comment: The problem is not the layout of `p1` (which is `GridBagLayout`).  The problem is the main (unnamed) panel.

Comment: The comment is saying what i said, isnt it.

Comment: No, your answer said that "there problem is the JPanel p1".  The problem is *not* in p1.  Also, you said that it's using the standard layout, which is specifically not the case.

Comment: I didnt say that it is the layout of JPanel p1.

Comment: The main panel is also not using standard layout, it's using `BorderLayout`.  This is easily provable: if it was using `FlowLayout`, which is the standard, the buttons would be on top, not on the bottom.